# How to add switch to UIView?

Tags: ios

I have a UIView with gestures added, how can I have switch-like functionality?
this is my code

```
@objc func funcName(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if (sender as AnyObject).isOn == true{
            print("It's on")
            
            
            AppearanceService.shared.theme = Themes.light
            view.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = AppearanceService.shared.theme.getUserInterfaceStyle()
            
            
        }else{
            print("It's off")
            
            
            
            AppearanceService.shared.theme = Themes.dark
            view.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = AppearanceService.shared.theme.getUserInterfaceStyle()
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: UIKit has this UI component for switches: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch Or what is it exactly you're asking?

Comment: I want to achieve black mode after click and turn to day mode on click.

Comment: I think you need to add some details for your question, what is it exactly you're asking. You mentioned you need a switch, here it is – `UISwitch`.